# update query not working for android

Tags: android

i have a simple table with three fields 
_id
name 
email

i am trying to update a record name by searching for email like

```
db.execSQL("update contacts set email='"+email+"' where name='"+name+"'");
```

even while running this with query it is not working

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name",n);
    dbase.update(table, cv, "email="+e,null);
```

can we run a query without primary key or what is the error in this.in the earlier case the application stops running.
appreciate any help in this.

Comment: [**i** is not **I**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun)).

Answer (score 0):

You can run update without primary key for sure. However if I get correctly what you need is the following:

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
cv.put("email",e);
String whereClause = "name = ?";
String [] whereArgs = {n};
dbase.update(table, cv, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

You want to search by `name` so here it is.

Always use `whereArgs` to set the `whereClause` parameters, otherwise you risk SQL injection - the parameters will not be sanitized (this is for this part of your code: `"email="+e`).

Comment: it is working now but was there any error in earlier code that was not working in execSQL or query .

Comment: @tejinder looking at the `query` solution of yours: you have swapped the places of your `where` and `set` clause. As you have written it you search by email and update the name. I can not tell what the problem with your `execSQL` might be.